# Xcode Error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift, xcode

I need some help with these codes because on the last 2 lines it says: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

```
func spawnEnemy(){

    let randomXStart = random(min: gameArea.maxX, max: gameArea.maxX)
    let randomXEnd = random(min: gameArea.minX, max:gameArea.maxX)
```

Comment: Show `random` method declaration.

Comment: There is no `random(min:max:)` function in the Swift  standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random is a function that is implemented by various scalar types like `Int` and `Float`. It takes a range as input.

You code should look like this:

```
func spawnEnemy(){

    let randomXStart = Int.random(in: gameArea.minX...gameArea.maxX)
    let randomXEnd = Int.random(in: gameArea.minX...gameArea.maxX)
    //your code here
}
```

Or if those values are in view coordinates, you might want to use CGFloat as the type:

```
let randomXStart = CGFloat.random(in: gameArea.minX...gameArea.maxX)
let randomXEnd = CGFloat.random(in: gameArea.minX...gameArea.maxX)
```